# PHP can't instance a new class via $this on public (PHP MVC)

Tags: php, class

**page.php** (Example Controller Page) opened as `http://page/view/`

```
class page extends fwcontroller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

    }

    public function view()
    {       
        $this->load->library("uri");  #DOESN'T WORK
        var_dump($this->load->library("uri"));  #DOESN'T WORK
    }
}
```

**fwcontroller.php** (Controller Hook, (it's on /fw/fwcontroller.php), I wan't move on another folder!)

```
class fwcontroller extends core
{
    public $load;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->load = new loader;

        var_dump($this->load->library("uri")); #OK

    }
}
```

**loader.php** (Loader library, (it's on /fw/loader.php), I wan't move on another folder!)

```
class function loader
{
    public function library($url)
    {
        return $url;
    }
}
```

I wan't loading instance on page controller via `$this->load->library("uri")` and return it's "ok". But works if I instance like "$this->loader = new loader" but only on a page.php not on fwcontroller.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: Please enable error reporting. Your syntax is way off.

```
public function page extends fwcontroller
```

Should be:

```
class page extends fwcontroller
```

And

```
public fwcontroller extends core
```

Should be:

```
class fwcontroller extends core
```

And

```
public function loader
```

Should be:

```
class loader
```

Another thing, it is better to do:

```
public function __construct(loader $loader) // or even better create a interface
{
    $this->load = $loader; // dependency injection is always better for among other thing testability

    var_dump($this->load->library("uri")); #OK

}
```

**EDIT**

How do you create an instance of the page class?

My guess is you do something like: `$instance = new page;` instead of doing: `$instance = new page();`. Because [it just works](http://viper-7.com/QLNVcP).

Comment: Sorry, but it's my tipfeler. It's a class. Ok

Comment: @JonathanKuhn What where? ;) OK missed that one :)

Comment: @phreakbox btw what is a tipfeler?

Comment: Works under class loader ("var_dump($this->load->library("uri")); #OK
") but not on class page page extends fwcontroller

Answer (score 0):

```
class /* NOT public function */ page extends fwcontroller
{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function view()
    {       
        $this->load->library("uri");  // should work now
        var_dump($this->load->library("uri")); // should work now
    }
}
```

(Correct other miss types!)

And use namespaces with autoloading function (+ dependency injection :P ).

Comment: On these class I setting up $load as public but works "$this->load->library("uri"); " only on public fwcontroller extends core (another folder).